# existing zpool assigned disk from datastore how to increase the zpool and increase the file system

Tags: solaris, zfs

First disk c1t0d0 is in syspool which is root file system. This disk is from datastore from esx host. If they increase existing disk for this Solaris VM server of syspool disk c1t0d0. How do I increase online the zpool and increase the root file system. Its created slice s0 on c1t0d0, what zpool and zfs commands I have to use here....

```
root@server:/var/fm/fmd# echo |format |more
Searching for disks...done


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c1t0d0 <DEFAULT cyl 4093 alt 2 hd 128 sec 32>
          /pci@0,0/pci15ad,1976@10/sd@0,0
       1. c1t1d0 <VMware-Virtual disk-1.0-500.00GB>
          /pci@0,0/pci15ad,1976@10/sd@1,0
       2. c3t0d0 <VMware-Virtual disk-1.0-1.00TB>
          /pci@0,0/pci15ad,790@11/pci15ad,1976@2/sd@0,0
Specify disk (enter its number): Specify disk (enter its number):
root@server:/var/fm/fmd#


  pool: syspool
 state: ONLINE
 scan: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        syspool     ONLINE       0     0     0
          c1t0d0s0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
root@server:/var/fm/fmd#


  pool: syspool
 state: ONLINE
 scan: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        syspool     ONLINE       0     0     0
          c1t0d0s0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
root@server:/var/fm/fmd#

root@server:/var/fm/fmd# df -h
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on
syspool/rootfs-nmu-000
                       7.8G   1.9G   1.7G    53%    /
/devices                 0K     0K     0K     0%    /devices
/dev                     0K     0K     0K     0%    /dev
ctfs                     0K     0K     0K     0%    /system/contract
proc                     0K     0K     0K     0%    /proc
mnttab                   0K     0K     0K     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                   1.2G   280K   1.2G     1%    /etc/svc/volatile
objfs                    0K     0K     0K     0%    /system/object
sharefs                  0K     0K     0K     0%    /etc/dfs/sharetab
/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap1.so.1
                       3.5G   1.9G   1.7G    53%    /lib/libc.so.1
fd                       0K     0K     0K     0%    /dev/fd
swap                   1.2G    40K   1.2G     1%    /tmp
swap                   1.2G    88K   1.2G     1%    /var/run
cterapool              1.5T   491M   152G     1%    /cterapool
syspool                7.8G    35K   1.7G     1%    /tmp/syspool
cterapool/cterafs      1.5T   1.2T   152G    90%    /usr/local/lib/ctera
cterapool/workfs       1.5T   105M   152G     1%    /usr/local/lib/cterawork
root@server:/var/fm/fmd#
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add disks to the pool. I can't tell you how to do that because it depends on a few things.

The the root file system / dataset should be able to use the new space automatically unless you have quota set.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see - seems like you have Solaris 10 there, because I see your root pool is on first Solaris slice. Thus, you cannot just increase the size of the virtual disk provided, you need also to resize your Solaris slice (I want to explicitly state that under *"Solaris slice"* I'm referring to the pertition of type *Solaris*, not to any of your Solaris partition).

The easy way, from my point of view, would be provide a new disk to your Solaris VM, a bigger one, label it accordingly (create similar Solaris partition for most of the disk), place loader on it (the procedure for Solaris 10 is described elsewehere) and attach it to the existing disk. Wait for resilver to complete, and detach old disk from mirror (I recommend using `zpool split` - just in case). Then you'll have a bigger disk.

Comment: "solaris slice" == fdisk partition